# Assign value of a column in a table as columname of another table

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a parent table `SalType` and in that table `Saltype_name` is the column name. Another table `StaffSal` which has foreign key relationship with `SalType`. In `StaffSal` I am entering values for each SalType_name

Table structure is like this

```
SalType --table1
SS_id  SalType_name
1      Basic
2      HRA
3      DA

StaffSal  --table2
SV_id  SS_id  SV_value   U_id
2       1       15000    11
3       2       0.1      11
4       3       0.75     11
5       1      10000     12
6       2       0.01     12
7       3       0.5      12
```

I need to display like this

```
U_id  Basic  HRA   DA ...
11    15000  .1    .75
12    10000  .01   .5
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways that you can transform the data from rows into columns.

SQL Server has a `PIVOT` function that can be applied to rotate the data.

If you have a finite number of values that you want transformed into columns, then you can hard-code the query:

```
select u_id, Basic, HRA, DA
from
(
  select t.saltype_name,
    s.u_id,
    s.sv_value
  from saltype t
  left join staffsal s
    on t.ss_id = s.ss_id
) src
pivot
(
  max(sv_value)
  for saltype_name in (Basic, HRA, DA)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8151f/4).

But if you have an unknown number of values, then you will want to implement dynamic SQL to generate the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(SalType_name) 
                    from SalType
                    group by SS_id, SalType_name
                    order by SS_id 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT u_id, ' + @cols + ' 
              from 
             (
                select t.saltype_name,
                  s.u_id,
                  s.sv_value
                from saltype t
                left join staffsal s
                  on t.ss_id = s.ss_id
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(sv_value)
                for saltype_name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8151f/2).

Both queries give the result:

```
| U_ID | BASIC |  HRA |   DA |
------------------------------
|   11 | 15000 |  0.1 | 0.75 |
|   12 | 10000 | 0.01 |  0.5 |
```

Comment: Also i want to show SS_id in the result. I tried to give that in ur query.But it shows the rows are repeating.Can u pls give me a solution

Comment: @Ajoe The problem is that `SS_id` is distinct so when the `GROUP BY` is applied in the query the you will generate multiple rows.

Comment: ya,but any way i need SS_id in that result set.do u have any suggestion?

Comment: @Ajoe Please ask a new question with the details on what you are trying to do. It will prevent the back and forth in the comments.

Comment: I need to manipulate the values of basic,hra etc. For that i need to take the SS_id in each cell of that table in asp.net mvc3

Comment: @Ajoe As I said, please post a new question with all of the details about the problem you are having.  Include in the question table, structure, sample data and the desired result because what you are requesting now is different from your original question here.

Comment: i added the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635076/manipulating-the-values-of-pivoted-table

Answer (score 1):

Pivot in sql server can be used to get the above result.

```
SELECT * FROM 
          (SELECT
               SV_value,
               SalType_name,
               U_id
           FROM 
              StaffSal
           INNER JOIN SalType 
                   ON StaffSal.SS_id= SalType.SS_id) AS SalaryDetails
PIVOT (SUM(SV_value) FOR SalType_name IN (HRA,Basic,DA)) AS PVT
```

Comment: Yes now i got the correct result. But the SalType_name will vary.Is it possible to give subquery to get the names in PIVOT (SUM(SV_value) FOR SalType_name IN (HRA,Basic,DA)) AS PVT

Comment: In such case we have to use dynamic sql.