# Calling a stored procedure in an MVC3 which returns a dataset

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am using a stored procedure which returns a dataset. My procedure is like this

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[USP_DisplaySaldetails]
 as begin
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(SST_Name) 
                from CM_SalType where SST_isdeleted='false'
                group by SST_id, SST_Name
                order by SST_id 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT U_id, ' + @cols + ' 
          from 
         (
            select t.SST_Name,
              s.U_id,u.U_Fname,u.U_lname,
              s.SSV_Value
            from CM_SalType t
            left join CM_StaffSal s
              on t.SST_id = s.SST_id inner join CM_User u on u.U_id=s.U_id
        ) x
        pivot 
        (                max(SSV_Value)
            for SST_Name in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

        execute(@query)
end
```

the result set is

```
| U_ID | BASIC |  HRA |   DA |
------------------------------
|   11 | 15000 |  0.1 | 0.75 |
|   12 | 10000 | 0.01 |  0.5 |
```

here the column names are dynamic.so how to call this procedure from mvc3 and how will i get the dataset into my controller. No parameters are passing to the stored procedure

Details of my table structure is in [Assign value of a column in a table as columname of another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543908/assign-value-of-a-column-in-a-table-as-columname-of-another-table/15544707#15544707). I am using entity framework

Comment: You'd call it the same way you'd call it from WinForms or WebForms. Please provide more detail, are you wanting to return this data as a HTML table or what?

Comment: ya i would like to get the data as a html table. more details about my tables are here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543908/assign-value-of-a-column-in-a-table-as-columname-of-another-table/15544707#15544707

Comment: I'm not able to give a full-answer, but get a `DataReader` or `DataTable` from your query, and convert it into a typed Model for your view, then iterate through the columns and rows in your view to render the HTML table.

Comment: i added a dataset and got the resultset in the controller page. From there i want to pass it to the view page as a JSON result. there its not displaying anything

Comment: I strongly suggest returning the data to the user in a standard HTML view as a `<table>` element rather than serving it asynchronously with JSON via a client-side action.

Comment: @ajoe: Are you using jqgrid in you view?